# Broadcast receiver listening for connectivity change firing at random intervals

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a Xamarin.Android application that is supposed to sync my data when the device it is running on connects to a WiFi network. To save data and battery I only let this happen whenever it detects a connections.

The only thing is, the application would randomly run the sync service multiple time throughout the day, despite the WiFi connection remaining constant. Now, I can only imagine that the Android system is sending out the broadcast multiple times to remind applications of the connection state or something like that.

I've used a bit of a quick fix, the static bool FirstTime there, but I'm hoping to find a bit more of an elegant solution. Any suggestions?

This is the code I'm using to do it:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" })]
class ConnectivityReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static bool FirstTime = true;
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if ( intent.Action != null && intent.Action == "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE") 
        {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
            NetworkInfo info = cm.ActiveNetworkInfo;
            if (FirstTime && info != null)
            {
                FirstTime = false;
                Intent background = new Intent(context, typeof(BackgroundDataSyncService));
                context.StartService(background);
            }else
            {
                FirstTime = true;
                Intent background = new Intent(context, typeof(BackgroundDataSyncService));
                context.StopService(background);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the code the only way this could happen is if the context.StopoService(background) statement is called more than once. Reason is that it sets FirstTime to true.  Put a trace point there and try to understand what that could be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a plugin called [Connectivity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Connectivity) that can pulled from nuget.
This plugin is compatible with almost every mobile platform and it can be used only in android it you want.
The plugin does all that code for you and you only have to subscribe to connectivity events like:

```
CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    page.DisplayAlert("Connectivity Changed", "IsConnected: " + args.IsConnected.ToString(), "OK");
};
```

The plugin has another nice features please take a look at the documentation.

Comment: Can I somehow use that as a broadcast receiver? Because this code needs to run even if the app is closed.

Comment: If you want to get notified when network change with the application closed you will have to have a Android Background Service that is launched when the system boots. 
At the launch of that service you will need to do CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged +=... to be notified even if the app is closed.
NOTE: The implementation of the plugin is already a broadcast receiver. You can see the source here: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Connectivity/Connectivity/Connectivity.Plugin.Android/ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver.cs

Answer (score 1):

Check the information in your Intent Bundle.  I had the same issue.
Whenever the system changes from WiFi to Cellular, or anything else weird happens in the system, the BroadCastReceiver will send out a message.
At first I thought this was a random event.
I also thought I had to use the ConnectivityManager to get the network information.
If you read the Intent Bundle that comes with the OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent), you'll get all kinds of information.

In my tests, I was working with Visual Studio's emulator.  I used the built in tools to switch from WiFi to Cell then kill off the signal, as well as change the signal strength.
I found that the BroadcastReceiver reports at least twice; once for the disconnect, and once for the reconnect.

Here is how I read the Bundle.

```
Bundle extras = intent.Extras;

if (extras != null)
{
   foreach (String key in extras.KeySet())
   {
        Object value = extras.Get(key);
        Log.Info("myApp", "intent.extras " + key + " " + value.ToString());
   }
}
```

You'll also find that one part of the Bundle contains the NetworkInfo too.

```
object netObj = extras.Get("networkInfo");
NetworkInfo netInf = null;

if (netObj != null)
{
    netInf = (NetworkInfo)netObj;
}
```

With this, you can check the status of different network functions.

```
Log.Info("myApp", "netInf.IsAvailable: " + netInf.IsAvailable.ToString());
Log.Info("myApp", "netInf.IsConnected: " + netInf.IsConnected.ToString());
```

I truly hope this helps someone.
I've been chasing this for days.

Comment: I forgot to add that is also fires when the system switches from 3G to 4G. 
Sample info:
intent.extras networkInfo [type: MOBILE[UNKNOWN], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: Contoso Wireless, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Xamarin.Essentials.Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged` event. Subscribe to this event.